# Debugging GWT's JavaScript in Intellij

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

When I debug GWT's client code from Intellij, debugger shows variable names as they are in compiled JavaScript and not as they were named in Java:

[image]

When I move mouse over some variable I get `ReferenceError`:

[image]

I thought it is the task of source maps to convert between js and java names.

Have I configured something incorrectly or is it just the current state of source maps?

Comment: I don't get anything at all on mouse over. But I see the same thing where all I get is the javascript debugging symbols, not the java ones. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears do be a [known GWT issue](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8460). Our developers are working with GWT team to support it in IDEA 15. You can track the progress [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8460).

You can already try [IDEA 15 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP) where it should partially work (not for all cases).